# Add Bootstrap dropdown class to a nav menu

Tags: menus, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

How to build this menu in WordPress

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">our story</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">our vision</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">History</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">History 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">History 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">History 3</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

WordPress Code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">

<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'header',
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'fallback_cb' => false
) );
?>

</div>
```

Comment: What's your code to build a nav menu without `dropdown` class?

Comment: Go through this link, you will get the idea. https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
                    
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>
                    
                </div>

Comment: For bootstrap 5: https://github.com/AlexWebLab/bootstrap-5-wordpress-navbar-walker

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use an off-the-shelf solution. There is a WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker class which extends WordPress' native Walker_Nav_Menu class and makes your Navigation Menus ready for Bootstrap 3 or 4. [Download it from GitHub](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker).

Add it to your theme, then add the following to the `functions.php`:

```
<?php
require_once('path-to-the-directory/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');
```

Change `path-to-the-directory/` to fit your needs.

Next, alter your `wp_nav_menu()` with the following code:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'header', // match name to yours
    'theme_location'    => 'header',
    'container'         => 'div', // no need to wrap `wp_nav_menu` manually
    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'      => 'collapse-1',
    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'fallback_cb'       => false,
    'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker() // Use different Walker
));
```

Note, that you don't need the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">` anymore as it will be added by `wp_nav_menu()` with proper CSS classes and `id`.

Also, read the WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker README.md file carefully.

Comment: Do you know if Navwalker is working with bootstrap 5?

Comment: @Lars Don't be shy. Google is your friend. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67331001/577418), [2](https://github.com/AlexWebLab/bootstrap-5-wordpress-navbar-walker) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use jquery in this case. You can add a new class in your functions.php file to check if the menu item has children and then add attributes to that item or use bootstrap nav walker as well. Here' I'm going with the easier one.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.sub-menu").parent().addClass("dropdown");
        $("ul.sub-menu").addClass("dropdown-menu");
        $("ul#menuid li.dropdown a").addClass("dropdown-toggle");
        $("ul.sub-menu li a").removeClass("dropdown-toggle"); 
        $('.navbar .dropdown-toggle').append('');
        $('a.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
    });
```

Just copy it and paste it in your footer.php.
For more details http://webtrickshome.com/faq/how-to-add-bootstrap-dropdown-class-in-wordpress-menu-item

Answer (score 0):

you can use  Walker_Nav_Menu class if you want to modify the default wordpress menu markup.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqTMhmjTBoE&list=PLriKzYyLb28kpEnFFi9_vJWPf5-_7d3rX&index=19